# Invalid command 'WSGIReloadMechanism' in my Apache site's config file

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a Django project and am using Apache2 with mod_wsgi.  Here are the relevant lines in my Apache conf file:

```
WSGIScriptReloading On
WSGIDaemonProcess myprojectcom
WSGIReloadMechanism Process
WSGIProcessGroup myprojectcom
WSGIApplicationGroup myprojectcom
WSGIPassAuthorization On

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myproject/myproject/deploy/deploy.wsgi
```

I've used a very similar conf file for many other deployments, but this is the first time that I'm getting the following error:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myproject.com:
Invalid command 'WSGIReloadMechanism', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
  ...fail!
```

I don't see any syntax error, though.  I'm on Ubuntu, using the libapache2-mod-wsgi package.  What could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the whole line:

```
WSGIReloadMechanism Process
```

It isn't needed any more and the directive was removed completely in mod_wsgi 3.X.

You should preferable not rely on old blog posts for how to set up mod_wsgi and use the actual mod_wsgi documentation on the mod_wsgi site instead.

Comment: Thanks so much!  One thing, though - I couldn't find in the docs how to check what version of mod_wsgi was on the server.

@Brandon, no need for the mean comment :(

Comment: If it is a binary package from a Linux distribution use the packaging tools to query what package verison is installed. If you can work out that, then setup the debugging WSGI script described in 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Displaying_Request_Environment'. In the output look at the value of 'mod_wsgi.version'.